# Do you call the common cold 'chill'?

Tags: word-choice

My friend (Russian native) says that the word 'chill' is fully synonymous to 'cold'. She says it's like saying 'the common cold'

I googled the definitions and I'm sure that 'chill' is when you're shaking in discomfort, but it's not the same thing. Do you call the common cold 'chill'? Or 'chill' is just one of its symptoms?

Comment: There is a nuance between a chill and a cold. A chill tends to be used for the illness when it is less severe than a cold. It is not a particularly common word in current British English and tends to be used by those who speak in a somewhat higher register.

Comment: Take Greybeard's explanation as one sense, one way the word is used (especially in the UK) (see [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chill_2) or Collins). This sense is 'pretty synonymous' with 'cold', with the provisos he states (I assume he's male). However,@Parth's definition is also valid. Both senses are in use, which probably explains why most people avoid using the term. Diseasewise, it can mean anything from a slight cold (and I'm cheating here really, citing the symptoms not the infecting agent) to malaria shakes. In the UK, malaria is thankfully rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chills refers to feeling cold after being in a cold environment. The word can also refer to an episode of shivering along with paleness and feeling cold.

According to wikipedia:

> Chills are commonly caused by inflammatory diseases, such as the flu. Malaria is one of the common reasons for chills and rigors. Chills is a feeling of coldness occurring during a high fever, but sometimes is also a common symptom which occurs alone in specific people. It occurs during fever due to the release of cytokines and prostaglandins as part of the inflammatory response, which increases the set point for body temperature in the hypothalamus

For more details check: https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003091.htm

Comment: Yeah, I've read that before. My question was "Is it common to call the common cold 'chill' or it's something my friend's confused about"

Comment: No it's not common. A common cold is a different thing altogether. Even in an expression chill can not be used to define a common cold

Comment: I would say no. Before it was understood that 'the common cold' is caused by a virus, people believed that it was caused by letting yourself get cold, so they would speak of 'catching a chill', but that usage is old-fashioned.